# Logistic regression when independent variable has both continuous and categorical data

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data

I'm working on a regression. The dependent variable is binary, and most of my independent variables are continuous, except one. For about 40% of the "age" variable, the data only says "> 5".

How in the heck do I treat that? Replace with the mean? Treat age as a dummy variable (really don't want to do this)? Consider it missing (ditto)?

Comment: Can you split on the discrete variable?  How many levels is it?  How many observations do you have?

Comment: Too many levels to split it.  About 2600 observations, with ages ranging from 0 to 96

Comment: Wait... so from 6 through 96 they are all coded as ">5"?

Comment: Can you make a new variable that splits on over 5 versus 5 and under?  This would give you two levels.  You might try to predict age given the other measures, and then use that.  Can you predict age given the other variables, then split model on the predicted age?  Does this work for all ages?

Comment: You could set it to missing and then do multiple imputation so it will end up being replaced with best guess values for some meaning of best guess.

Comment: No, sadly.  That's what's confusing me.  I have continuous values from 0 to 96 _and also_ this block of people whose age is only listed as >5

Comment: If you have some ages over 5, and some that are enumerated, then you can likely make a decent estimator of actual age.

Comment: I'd also suggest checking if the data set is compiled/entered correctly. I had situations in which this ">5" could be one of the answer for the next question but for some reason an accidental skip happened and errors like this happened.

Comment: Is this machine learning to allow imputation, or is it descriptive analysis?

Comment: @Firebug: it's descriptive analysis